# what is the GMail email OAuth URL API to get Google Mails using Google OAuth2?

Tags: php, oauth, gmail

When I tried to get contacts it worked perfectly, but what request or URL should I invoke to get the **emails** from Gmail?

This is a working code sample to get Google Contacts:

```
$xmlresponse= file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?oauth_token='.$accessTokenN.'&max-results=100');
```

Answer (score 2):

there isn't a data api for gmail

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/faq.html#GmailAtomFeed